# IMP-00009 and IMP-00018: abnormal end of export file partial import of previous table completed: 10865925 rows imported

Tags: database, oracle

**I'm getting tired to backup and restore Oracle database but it's shown same error every time please anyone tell me what's the solution of this**

what's the reason for getting this type of error

*IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file*

```
Warning: the objects were exported by PSSL, not by you

import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. importing PSSL's objects into SYS
. . importing table                   "APPS_OPBAL"       6209 rows imported
. . importing table                   "APPS_OPSTK"       4128 rows imported
. . importing table                    "BCL_AVGPL"      37410 rows imported
. . importing table                     "CL_BONUS"       4811 rows imported
. . importing table                 "CL_BSREVERSE"       2509 rows imported
. . importing table                   "CL_BUYSALE"     160742 rows imported
. . importing table                   "CL_CDBLFEE"      16178 rows imported
. . importing table                   "CL_CDBLSTK"      26623 rows imported
. . importing table               "CL_CERTIFICATE"       6921 rows imported
. . importing table                 "CL_MRATE_CSE"     368606 rows imported
. . importing table                 "CL_MRATE_DSE"          0 rows imported
 . . importing table                   "CL_RECEIVE"      13868 rows imported
. . importing table                  "CL_RECV_MST"       4057 rows imported
. . importing table                 "CL_REFERENCE"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "CL_REFMST"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "CL_REQPAY"       9666 rows imported
. . importing table                "CL_REQPAY_MST"       5353 rows imported
. . importing table                     "CL_RIGHT"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                       "CL_SEC"          2 rows imported
. . importing table                "CL_SETTLEMENT"       1905 rows imported
. . importing table               "CL_TRANS_CHQRP"      23208 rows imported
. . importing table                   "GL_ACCHART"       7868 rows imported
. . importing table              "GL_ACCHART_CTRL"        198 rows imported
. . importing table              "GL_BALANCESHEET"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "GL_BSHEET"         21 rows imported
. . importing table                   "GL_CHQBOOK"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                     "GL_CHQNO"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "GL_CHQNO1"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "GL_MASTER"     231583 rows imported
. . importing table                     "GL_RECON"      28685 rows imported
. . importing table                     "GL_TRANS"       7593 rows imported
. . importing table                  "GL_TRANS_JV"      30067 rows imported
. . importing table                  "NGTS_CLIENT"      53159 rows imported
. . importing table                  "NGTS_SCRIPT"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                    "PCL_AVGPL"      37489 rows imported
. . importing table                    "PCL_BAL25"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                  "PCL_BALANCE"    5193623 rows imported
. . importing table                   "PCL_BAL_CL"    4750948 rows imported
. . importing table              "PCL_BAL_MATURED"      21862 rows imported
. . importing table                   "PCL_BAL_OP"    4736213 rows imported
. . importing table                "PCL_BAL_TRANS"     205464 rows imported
. . importing table                  "PCL_BUYSALE"      74671 rows imported
. . importing table              "PCL_BUYSALE0206"        392 rows imported
. . importing table                    "PCL_NETPL"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                "PCL_RECVISSUE"      14724 rows imported
. . importing table                   "PCL_STK_CL"    4957536 rows imported
. . importing table              "PCL_STK_MATURED"      37934 rows imported
. . importing table                   "PCL_STK_OP"   13439383 rows imported
. . importing table                 "PCL_STK_RATE"   13457171 rows imported
. . importing table                    "PCL_STOCK"
IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file
IMP-00018: partial import of previous table completed: 10865925 rows imported
Import terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Comment: Did you check the export logs? Did you saw some error during export?

Comment: yes i checked it again there is no error

Comment: Importing into SYS is a really bad idea. Maybe include the full export and import commands for reference. Has the dump file been compressed, or moved between machines/architectures, or FTP'd? There's no way for us to tell what is wrong with your file, unfortunately.